# Can a function argument be scoped automatically in Coq?

Tags: coq

Suppose I'm working on an environment which frequently mixes nat and Z. If for example I have

```
Require Import List ZArith.
Import ListNotations.
Open Scope Z_scope.
Definition f (l : list nat) := l.
Compute f [1;3].
```

Coq tells me `The term "[1; 3]" has type "list Z" while it is expected to have type "list nat".`
Of course I can just write `[1;3]%nat` but I was wondering if there was a better way, since usually there's no ambiguity.

A related question is: can I avoid having to scope manually a notation argument?

```
Notation "\\\ l ///" := (f l).
Compute \\\[1;3]///. (* same error as before *)
```

Comment: I would have thought that the `Arguments` command gives a solution to your problem, but it does not work as I expect.

Comment: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/extensions/arguments-command.html?highlight=arguments#binding-arguments-to-a-scope  This section explicitly states that scopes given to the function are not propagated to subterms, bummer.